# How to define an action as separated class in SF2?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, symfony, yii, action

I have been worked with YF some time and I know that in YF is a beautiful thing - an ability to define an action as separated class. Look [this page](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller) (paragraph - 3. Action) for details.

I wonder, is it possible to do it in SF2?

For SF I found the following solution: extending a class sfAction. What about SF2?

Comment: You can the same sort of thing.  Read through the manual.

Comment: I did not find... Google did not return any results for SF2.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have a problem that has no use for very little other users finding it. Only because you want to do something, this must not qualify as a question. I suggest you make more clear *what* you are trying to do and *why*. Which problem should that solve for example? And why don't you just use the standard symfony2 action suggestion to instantiate each of your action objects? I mean, just write the code, it should work. It's PHP, nothing specific to symfony2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony 2.x is not an MVC framework. There is no defined way how you must create your controllers, views or the model layer. The framework is only providing the supporting structures.

That said, the idea to create a separate object of action is stupid (it was stupid when Symfony 1.x did it and it is still stupid when Yii nicked).

Controller is structure which is supposed to only change the sate of model layer and current view. It does not create objects, it does not render output. It just the details about user input and directs it to model layer or view. Having a separate class for an action is pointless.